# How to deny DHCP broadcast by MAC address?

Tags: router, dhcp

I live in an school dormitory where the network/internet is managed by the building. One day, some genius decided to plug their ethernet into their personal abandoned router's LAN port, or perhaps that person just want to boost WiFi, who knows. As a result, I get IP broadcast from this dud router from time to time. The building tech came and pointed out the same problem, but he implied that he doesn't know who is doing this and can't do anything.

Hopefully, I can deny any broadcast from this device. Also, could this be the reason I sometime have really high ping?

Comment: Are you saying there is a rogue DHCP server on the ethernet, or a wireless network you don't want to connect to? If it's a rogue DHCP server on the ethernet the university IT people need to track that down and disable the port. If it's wifi, telling your computer to forget a given WIFI network is trivial and well documented process.

Answer (score 0):

> but he implied that he doesn't know who

That could be easily found out with a bit of network sniffing...

The rogue DHCP response comes from a specific MAC address, you can set up a firewall filter to filter it those packets. (e.g. `iptables` on Linux).

First you must sniff the responses to identify the rogue MAC address, e.g. with `wireshark`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this requires the network to be engineered to only allow connections from known MAC addresses (ie this needs to be done at the switch level).  Really, your ability to control this type of problem depends almost entirely on the capabilities of your switch (unless you reengineer your network, for example to require pppoe)

You should be able to identify the MAC address of the rogue DHCP server - by looking at the broadcast traffic.  You can then use the first 3 octets of the dhcp server,  which may give you a hint at the make of the device you are after.

Hack to help you trsce the issue down (assuming a dumb network)

I might get a device  (eg a Linux box) where I can run a DHCP client in the foreground.  Id then block this mac address from the official dhcp server.  At this point I could disable/disconnect 1 switch port at a time, and then do a dhcp request and see if its answered, repeating until ive tracked down the port of the dhcp client.  This would cause a short outage on each port, so might be best done when the network is fairly quiet.